# shell_exec not working with .sh scripts

Tags: php, shell, permissions

I have a php file hosted on apache server in Ubuntu. Everything works fine apart from `shell_exec('myscript.sh')`.

If I execute anything like `shell_exec('dir')`, `shell_exec('ls')`, etc., it works fine. But only when I am executing a simple shell script through `shell_exec`, it doesn't work.

For simplicity I have put just an `echo` command within shell script. The same script works when I execute through the terminal. Like:

```
# sh myscript.sh // works perfectly fine
```

But not from the PHP, below is my php code

```
<?php     
$result = shell_exec('myscript.sh');    
echo $result;     
?>
```

Notes:

- Safe mode is off
- `shell_exec` is not there in disable_functions list
- Both php and .sh file are in the same folder

Thanks

Comment: .sh file is marked as executable and webserver user has execute permissions?  You use `./script.sh`?

Comment: so what should i do now? any suggestions

Comment: Try making your `shell_exec` *exactly* the same as your terminal attempt: `shell_exec('sh myscript.sh')`.

Comment: when i do # php myFile.php from terminal it works fine, but not through the browser. plz plz plz suggest me the solution :)

Comment: Sounds like the user PHP is running as doesn't have permission to run/execute the file.

Comment: How can i give the permission to the user

Comment: What does the following print out: `var_dump(shell_exec('whoami'), shell_exec('groups'), substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('myscript.sh')), -4));`?

Comment: shell_exec('groups')=shell_exec('whoami')=--> www-data

Answer (score 2):

Try giving PHP ownership of the file.

`chown phpusername:phpusername myscript.sh`
or the same for the apache user.

If that doesn't work, try `chmod 777 myscript.sh` but that is generally a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: Where `phpusername` is *probably* `www-data`.

Comment: @jazean: Did you try `shell_exec('sh myscript.sh')`?  You might need to make it executable first: `chmod +x myscript.sh`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat and apacheusername is <i>probably</i> `nobody`

@jazean Long shot here: Where does myscript.sh live, and where does your php script live?

Comment: in the same folder /var/www/

Answer (score 0):

I ti think it should be

```
$result = shell_exec('./myscript.sh');
```

Comment: @jazean make sure if file is executable for all users chmod a+x myscript.sh or paste error you are getting form execution of php script.

Comment: i m not receiving an error , but the script within it is not executing

Answer (score 0):

It is because you need to escape the command as bash argument.  And for that to work, you need to use double quotes wrapping inside your command, and finally, use 2>&1 as a closing piece along with your desired script function command.

i.e.

```
   $xarg = escapeshellarg("./myscript.sh 2>&1");
   $result = shell_exec("$xarg");
```

and keep in your mind, the interaction between php and bash is unique.  PHP always hang up waiting on bash.  Even though if that script is fired, your php should expect to move on to next line in script without waiting on bash after function is called.

Comment: Oh yes... and on your bash script, you need to identify $xarg as actual arugment.  Empty argument, such like your script firing a command on its own, is always $1.   Hence, you would want to identify inside your bash with this:  $xarg=$1.  This establishes the relationship between both script before bash can accept to proceed.

Comment: sorry i did not understand, should i change anything in myscrip.sh file? coz i tried the above and it did not work

Comment: #!/bin/bash
$xarg=$1
your script blah blah
exit 0

Comment: #php myFile.php was working just before from the terminal, but i executed some permissions as suggested in the discussion, now i m getting an error saying test.sh permission denied and now it is not working from the terminal as well

Comment: fire this command line: sudo tail /var/log/syslog and this will tell you why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Okay , i got the solution. The problem was the php file and .sh file should be in the same group of users and all the other files which are being accessed by php and .sh file should be also in the same group

so,

addgroup myGroupName toOtherGroupName

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I just use

```
$res = passthru($cmd);
```

and everything works .
This is  my code you may have different results .

```
function flv_convert($in,$out_vid)
{$cmd ='/usr/bin/avconv -i '.$in.' -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 230k -bufsize 64k -s 640x360 -an '.$out_vid.'  2>&1 1> /dev/null';
$res = passthru($cmd);       }
$in = $_POST['url'];
$out_vid = reset(explode('.',$in)).'O.mp4' ;
if (  flv_convert($in, $out_vid)  )
echo 'done ';else echo '  <p>Fail</p>   '
```